# Picasso image not showing from some url

Tags: android, image, picasso

I have downloaded the picasso example app source code from [here](https://github.com/tutorialwing/android-picasso-example) . It works fine but when i changed the url to my own server image not showing.

Here is my code

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Picasso.with(this)
            .load("http://try-it.epizy.com/routine/api/capture.png")
            .into(imageView);
```

And also logcat is below:

```
                                                                               [ 07-09 21:39:18.189 17487:17540 D/         ]
                                                                             [Posix_connect Debug]Process tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary :80 
07-09 21:39:18.212 17487-17487/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0xa31e4000)
07-09 21:39:18.212 17487-17543/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0x96483000 initialize window=0xa31e4000, title=tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary.MainActivity
07-09 21:39:18.212 17487-17543/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0xa31e4000,api=1)
07-09 21:39:18.213 17487-17543/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary W/libEGL: [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
07-09 21:39:18.220 17487-17543/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
07-09 21:39:18.229 17487-17487/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#81810100
07-09 21:39:18.241 17487-17543/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xadf34580) (w:720 h:1440 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
07-09 21:39:18.250 17487-17543/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xadf34700) (w:720 h:1440 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
07-09 21:39:18.794 17487-17540/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary I/System.out: [socket][/10.54.86.142:46615] connected
07-09 21:39:18.795 17487-17540/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
07-09 21:39:18.795 17487-17540/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
07-09 21:39:19.329 17487-17540/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary D/skia: --- SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null
07-09 21:39:19.329 17487-17540/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary D/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded with stream
07-09 21:39:19.329 17487-17540/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary D/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded: [47][106][97][118][97]
07-09 21:39:19.330 17487-17540/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary D/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded: headerSize = 27183
07-09 21:39:19.330 17487-17540/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary D/DRM/DcfDecoder: isDrmFile: version is not dcf version 1, no oma drm file
07-09 21:39:19.845 17487-17664/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
07-09 21:39:19.845 17487-17664/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
07-09 21:39:20.385 17487-17664/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary D/skia: --- SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null
07-09 21:39:20.385 17487-17664/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary D/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded with stream
07-09 21:39:20.385 17487-17664/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary D/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded: [47][106][97][118][97]
07-09 21:39:20.385 17487-17664/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary D/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded: headerSize = 27183
07-09 21:39:20.385 17487-17664/tutorialwing.com.picassolibrary D/DRM/DcfDecoder: isDrmFile: version is not dcf version 1, no oma drm file
```

Comment: Please try Glide [link](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Comment: sure i will try.but i want to know is there any issue  with Picasso?

Comment: please log by using `Picasso.with(Context).setLoggingEnabled(true)` and check, it might show the error message with some reason.

Comment: Can you try to use last version of picasso?

Comment: tried latest version but nothing happened.